# Passing parameters into heredoc

Tags: bash

I'm trying to add a service under the name of `$1.service`, however, the service file being created is not getting the `$1`, instead, only `.service`

also there is a part where `$1` needs to be pasted inside the `$1.service` file but it's not passing that information through as well.

this is basically how my bash script look like;

```
#! /bin/bash

function addService {
  cat << EOF > /etc/systemd/system/$1.service
  (all that service stuff here)
  PIDFile=${_var}/$1.pid
  EOF
}

cfg_file=~/config/"$cfg.conf"
if [ -f "$cfg_file" ]; then
  . "$cfg_file"
  addService $1
fi
```

so you run the script as `./script.sh test` and it should create a service called `test.service` in this example, but it doesn't seem to be working properly. however, the variables like `${_conf}` are passing through without any problems.

and also, do I have to use `EOF` specifically for this task or `echo` would do the job alone?

EDIT:

The config file exists and it is `$1+.conf` and this is the content of `test.conf` file;

```
_var=var1
```

and the `.service` file that is created passing this information without any problems. which means if `$1` wasn't working, it wouldn't fetch the config file as well. but apparently, it is working.

Comment: Isn't there a `shift` in the cfg_file?

Comment: oh, I see. there is no `shift` in the cfg_file. is it necessary by the way?

Comment: It could change $1, so it could break your script.

Comment: We need to see what's in the config file. It looks like it's erasing `$1`. Try `echo "$1"` immediately before and after the `. "$cfg_file"` line to see if that's what's happening.

Comment: config file only has this; `_var=var1` and nothing else

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Your question is too fragmented to properly diagnose the issue. In particular, if the config file isn't relevant to the question then remove it so we don't get sidetracked.

Comment: `EOF` being indented, this heredoc won't parse correctly at all.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are checking for the existence of a file in ~/conf that ends in .conf?  What is the value of $cfg?  Does ~/conf/${cfg}.conf exist?  If not, are you even going into the if clause?  Using "set -x" will help debug these things.

Second, you have EOF indented.  For HERE documents, the delimiter must start in the first column.  You should have gotten an error when running this script about that.  Something like, here-document at line X delimited by end-of-file (wanted EOF).  The delimiter string can be anything (e.g. EOSD for end of service definition).  It needs to start in column 1 though.

Here is what I quickly did to make sure things work.

```
#! /bin/bash

set -x

function addService {
  cat << EOF > ./$1.service
  (all that service stuff here)
  PIDFile=${_conf}/$1.pid
EOF
}

cfg_file=./conf.in
if [ -f "$cfg_file" ]; then
  . "$cfg_file"
  addService $1
fi
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: .conf file exists and this is it's only content; `_var=var1`. I'll try your suggestion now

Answer (score -1):

The problem has been solved by changing

```
cat << EOF > /etc/systemd/system/$1.service
  (service content here)
EOF
```

to

```
echo "
  (service content here)
" > /etc/systemd/system/$1.service
```

Comment: That's a workaround, though, not a fix. Heredocs absolutely **can** do what you're looking for here, but without a MCVE we can't track down the issue.